# How to access XAMPP mysql database outside of htdocs folder

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I need to access the MySQL server from my local website located outside of htdocs folder. When I enter XAMPP server credentials, it shows:

```
NO FILE OR ROOT DIRECTORY FOUND
```

Is there some config settings I can change in XAMPP's config file to allow access?

Answer (score -1):

In order to connect remotely you have to have MySQL bind port 3306 to your machine's IP address in my.cnf. Then you have to have created the user in both localhost and '%' wildcard and grant permissions on all DB's as such . See below:

my.cnf (my.ini on windows)

```
#Replace xxx with your IP Address 
bind-address        = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

then

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Then

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

Depending on your OS you may have to open port 3306 to allow remote connections.